# Drag and drop content on user side

Tags: nodes, 6

I am developing a Drupal 6 site in which I need to allow user to drag and drop 
blocks of content, but the arrangement of the content for each particular user should be persistent whenever they visit the site. I have completed the drag and drop functionality but after each refresh the content reverts to its original layout.

Here is the example site: http://portal.opera.com/

How can I make the results of D&D functions persistent?

Answer (score 0):

Save the arrangement of blocks using some client side storage (e.g. cookies) when it is changed. After the page is loaded, use JavaScript to recreate the arrangement from the stored information.